# Mutual independence, pairwise independence, and conditional independence

Tags: probability

Suppose $X, Y, Z$ are random variables.

1. Does the following statements together imply that $X, Y, Z$ are
   mutually independent:

   - $(X,Y)$ and $Z$ are independent
   - $X$ and $Y$ are independent?
2. Does the following statements together imply that $X, Y, Z$ are
   mutually independent:

   - $(X,Y)$ and $Z$ are independent
   - $X$ and $Y$ are conditionally independent on $Z$?

What are  similar results for $X_1, \dots, X_n$ to be mutually independent?

My questions were inspired from [Dilip's comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/698918/15941).
Thanks!

Comment: Please edit your [previous question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/698918/15941) instead of asking a separate one about the same issue.

Comment: can you enlighten me why they are the same question/issue? For example, does an answer to one post lead to an answer to the other?

Comment: When you write $(X,Y)$, do you mean a random vector distributed according to the product distribution $\mu_X\times\mu_Y$ (where $\mu_X$ and $\mu_Y$ are the distributions of $X$ and $Y$ resp.)?

Comment: Yes, @RaisinBread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1.** Let $A,B,C\in\mathscr B(\mathbb R)$ be arbitrary Borel sets. Since $X$ and $Y$ are independent, we have that
\begin{align*}
\Pr[X\in A]\Pr[Y\in B]\Pr[Z\in C]=\Pr\Big([X\in A]\cap[Y\in B]\Big)\Pr[Z\in C].\tag{1}
\end{align*}
Now, $(X,Y)\in A\times B$ if and only if $X\in A$ and $Y\in B$,
so the above becomes
\begin{align*}
\Pr[X\in A]\Pr[Y\in B]\Pr[Z\in C]=\Pr[(X,Y)\in A\times B]\Pr[Z\in C].\tag{2}
\end{align*}
Since $A\times B$ is a *measurable rectangle*,
it certainly is in the Borel $\sigma$-algebra $\mathscr B(\mathbb R\times\mathbb R)$.
Thus,
since $(X,Y)$ and $Z$ are independent,
it follows from $(2)$ that
\begin{align*}
\Pr[X\in A]\Pr[Y\in B]\Pr[Z\in C]&=\Pr\Big([(X,Y)\in A\times B]\cap[Z\in C]\Big)\\
&=\Pr\Big([X\in A]\cap[Y\in B]\cap[Z\in C]\Big)\tag{3}.
\end{align*}
From this you can easily conclude that $X,Y$ and $Z$ are mutually independent: For instance, let $A=\mathbb R$ in $(3)$, and you get
\begin{align*}
\Pr[Y\in B]\Pr[Z\in C]&=\Pr[X\in\mathbb R]\Pr[Y\in B]\Pr[Z\in C]\\
&=\Pr\Big([X\in \mathbb R]\cap[Y\in B]\cap[Z\in C]\Big)\\
&=\Pr\Big([Y\in B]\cap[Z\in C]\Big).
\end{align*}

Part 2. can probably be done using similar reasoning.

As for extending this to a finite collection $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ of random variables, I suspect that carefully examining steps $(1)$ and $(2)$ will help you find a general statement.